# Trying to display NEO4J data in a html page through json

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, neo4j

I wanted to display the nodes present in the Neo4j graph data-base.
And I have used alchemy.min.js and achemy.min.css through cdn of graphalchemist.com. But it shows a blank page and in the console it shows an error. Here output:

[image]

Here html:

[image]

Please help me solve this error.And suggest me if there is a better way of displaying the nodes of neo4j and its relationships.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the error in the console it shows an unexpected token of '<' i.e. left angle bracket.

This is a common error when your resource is an html file instead of a js or css file (in this case it should be a js file.) Try changing your link and finding the file elsewhere as your js cdn file leads to a squatter site right now. http://cdn.graphalchemist.com/alchemy.min.js You can check by clicking that.

When you check the link of your cdn it should display a "plain text" page black on white kind of deal.

**EDIT:**

Try this cdn link instead: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alchemyjs/0.4.2/alchemy.min.js

You can see the rest of them here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/alchemyjs.

Comment: Yeah john, it displays a page with a black background.And when I check the console of that page.It says "err:: domain blocked by client".Thanks a lot.

Comment: @saitejapasula Just use the link in the edit portion instead. Sorry for not being super clear, but I wouldn't download anything from that site you linked originally for the .min.js file it's a squatter site. That link to that now squatter site was most likely the javascript file you were looking for at some point previously, but now they seemed to have moved their site somewhere else and now someone else bought the domain to that site and they just keep it until someone will buy the domain from them for a higher price.

Comment: When I include the CDN you have mentioned here.It shows "_ is not defined".Please help me out with this.

Comment: @saitejapasula I was looking through the docs and it said it has some extra dependencies https://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/docs it states it in the quick start section. It says you can load in all the dependencies with the vendor.css and vendor.js files. That link where I said the rest of the cdn links are contains those. I'll also post them here. vendor.css: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alchemyjs/0.4.2/styles/vendor.css. vendor.js: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alchemyjs/0.4.2/scripts/vendor.js.

Comment: @saitejapasula most likely the '_ is not defined' is talking about lodash that is one of the dependencies, but don't worry about adding it individually it should already be added in the vendor.js code.

Comment: I have figured it out. And you have helped me solve this issue john. Thanks a ton. cheers

Comment: @saitejapasula glad I could help.